# как получить body из okhttp и дождаться ответа

Tags: android, kotlin, http, get, okhttp

код:

```
val client = OkHttpClient()
    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .build()
    client.newCall(request)
        .enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                runOnUiThread {
                    val x = file.getcurrencykeys()!!.toMutableList()
                    val y = file.getcurrencyvalues()!!.toMutableList()
                    for (i in 0..x.size - 1) {
                        mapc[x[i]] = y[i].toFloat()
                    }
                    binding.textView5.setText(file.gettime())
                    val t =
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Переход в оффлайн режим", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    t.show()
                }
            }
            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                println(response.body)
            }
        })
```

вывод:

```
I/System.out: okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody@6334d3f
```

не понимаю в чом ошибка(код респонса 200), также не очень понимаю как дождаться ответа от такой конструкции, обьясните пожалуйста где ошибся

Comment: Попробуйте response.body.string()

Comment: получилось спасибо а не подскажете как ждать ответа от функции

Comment: Что значит ждать? Это асинхронный код, ждать не получится) возможно вам надо что-то  типа реактивности. Посмотрите flow для корутин или rxJava

Comment: ну мне нужно загружать данные в приложении по этим данным при открытии и оно должно произойти до того как приложение запуститься тоесть это все должно происходить во время загрузки а после приложение должно открыться что посоветуете использовать

Comment: Отложить запуск приложения, запущенного по иконке из списка приложений до тех пор пока не пройдёт к-л асинхронная операция - невозможно. Наверное, вам надо просто какой-то блокирующий UI показать пока не придёт ответ с сервера. Например показывайте ProgressBar на весь экран. И/или фрагмент в котором этот ProgressBar будет

Comment: да так и сделал обным textview, спасибо